# loadlibrary fails for current path with GetLastError() == 0

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

I have a simple program that loads a DLL from the current path

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

auto loaddll(const char * library) {
    auto dllModule = LoadLibrary(library);
    if(dllModule == NULL)
        throw "Can't load dll";     
    return dllModule;
}

int main() {
    try {   
        auto Handle = loaddll("ISab.dll");
    } catch(const char * error) {
        cerr << "An Unexpected error :" << error << endl;   
        cerr << "Get Last Error : " << GetLastError();
    }
}
```

the load library fails for every DLL in the current path but succeeds for DLL like User.dll

if I ran it output will be like

```
An Unexpected error :Can't load dll
Get Last Error : 0
```

this also fails if i specify full path to dll

Comment: `GetLastError()` is supposed to be called *immediately* after the function that caused the error. Otherwise it might be overwritten by internal system calls, in this case propably during output to `cerr`.

Comment: Don't change a question to a different one, thereby invalidating answers you have already received. I rolled back your changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a Win32 API call fails, and sets the error code, you must call `GetLastError` before calling any other Win32 API function. You don't do that.

Raising an exception, streaming to `cerr` etc. are all liable to call other Win32 API functions and so reset the error code.

Your code must look like this:

```
auto dllModule = LoadLibrary(library);
if (dllModule == NULL)
    auto err = GetLastError();
```

Once you have the error code you should be better placed to understand why the module could not be loaded. Common error codes for `LoadLibrary` include:

- `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` which means that the module, or one of its dependencies, cannot be located by the DLL search.
- `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` which invariably means a 32/64 bit mismatch, either with the module you load, or one of its dependencies.

Comment: `implement a custom exception class` - in most cases `std::system_error` will be sufficient.

Comment: That's `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` isn't it.

Comment: @zett42: Do you happen to have a link to a resource, that thoroughly explains `std::system_error`, preferably as it applies to Windows API programming? I'm still having a hard time understanding, how it should be used, and why.

Comment: i added some error checking can you please have look on it

Comment: okay got it "is not a valid Win32 application" but I am using the dll in pascal(inno setup) for a long time

Comment: As I said, invariably that is due to a 32/64 bit mismatch. I think we are done here, no?

Comment: @IInspectable I don't think I have one. I got my knowledge from here and there. There isn't so much to `std::system_error` if you only want to use it for transporting OS error codes (`throw std::system_error(errorCode, std::system_category(), message);`). It gets more involved only if one wants to implement a custom error category (usually for transporting error codes of third party libraries).

Comment: @IInspectable I have a [bookmark](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-1.html) that explains a bit of the *why* from one of the designers of `<system_error>`.

Comment: yes sir, thanks, the problem is 32/64 mismatch, compiling with mingw32 got me